# Generic button component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started play with React and I'm stuck with this sample.

Counter works but why onClick the BUTTON does not change key active in state and render correct button?

Link to [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dariuszsobkowicz/full/qRLyLy/)

```
  const Button = ({label}) => (
    <button className="btn btn-primary">{label}</button>
);

const Counter = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            counter: 0,
            active: false
        }
    },

    increment: function () {
        this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter + 1
        })
    },

    change: function () {
       this.setState({
           active: true
       })
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Counter: {this.state.counter}</h1>
                    <button onClick={this.increment}>1+</button>}
                    {this.state.active ? 
                    <Button label="Sign OUT"/> :
                    <Button label="Sign in" onClick={this.change}/>}
                </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you forgot to define `click` event in `Button` Component use this:

```
const Button = (props) => (
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={props.onClick}>{props.label}</button>
);
```

one more thing, you need to define the click event with `signout` button also, like this:

```
{this.state.active ? 
    <Button label="Sign OUT" onClick={this.change}/> : 
    <Button label="Sign in" onClick={this.change}/>
} 

change: function () {
    this.setState({
        active: !this.state.active
    })
}
```

Check working example:

`jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/mtbg3g59/

`Codepen`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRLgpp

Comment: Thanks that help a lot

Comment: glad, to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your button doesn't take a prop named onClick so it's normal t hat it does nothing, try to change its definition to this and it should work

```
const Button = ({label}, {onClick}) => (
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={onClick}>{label}</button>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

On page load `this.state.active` is set to false therefore the "Sign OUT" button is rendered, which has no onClick attribute. I think you want your code to look something like this:

```
{this.state.active ? 
                <Button label="Sign OUT" onClick={this.change}/> :
                <Button label="Sign in"/>}
```